# Monitor network traffic on Android

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

I'm interested in what kind of network traffic my Android phone is using when using my home wifi. I can't root my phone, but I have full access to my home router.
Is it possible to check what kind of traffic and when my phone is sending out or receiving?

Comment: Please clarify "what kind of traffic", do you mean "which programs (apps) are accessing the network/internet"? Because you can't do that from the router. Root access probably isn't necessary, I use `Onavo` unrooted to do this on mobile data. Also, `superuser` is for computer related issues, you probably want [http://android.stackexchange.com/](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Which apps/when/what they send out is what I would like to know... Or at least what.

Comment: Technically, yes, it is possible. But how to actually do it is largely dependent on your router itself. What model do you have (or have in mind)?

Comment: @Bob, I'd recommend the user to ask a similar question on Android, which focuses on apps that let him track his network traffic. The question of tracking traffic through a router is certainly on-topic for SU

Answer (score 2):

You can [ARP spoof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) your phone from your computer and capture all the raw packets with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) to examine them.

Other way would be to turn your computer into an access-point, run wireshark on it, connect your phone to the network through that computer and capture the packets.

Comment: The second way sounds reasonable. I will try to do it, hopefully I'm successful with it.